# Extract image from Json

Tags: json, xcode, uiimage

I´ve created this Json:

```
{"daysWeek":[
{
"titleInside":"Monday",
"descriptionInside":"First",
"image":"http://example.com/monday.jpg",
},
{
"titleInside":"Tuesday",
"descriptionInside":"Second",
"image":"http://example.com/Tuesday.jpg",
}]
}
```

I´ve already extract the information of "titleInside" and "descriptionInside" and put them in my tableView as follows:

```
    NSDictionary *days = [self.daysWeek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [days objectForKey:@"titleInside"];
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = [days objectForKey:@"descriptionInside"]
```

But i don´t know how to put the images into:

```
cell.thumbImage.image=?
```

I´d really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to download the image and then use the resultant data to configure the `UIImage`. If this is in a table view cell you should load them asynchronously.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: days[@"image"]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    });
});
```

I would recommend looking into `AFNetworking` and their `UIImageView` categories for doing stuff like this in the future.

Comment: @XCode4S If it worked please be sure to accept the answer and upvote. Thank You.